# Compiling Intellij-Project in the command line

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a project which I created in Intellij via command line but for some reason it raises a `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest`. I added some additional libraries in the `/lib`-folder in Intellij and compiling it works just fine.
The command I am using is:
`javac TwitterAPI_Finish.java -cp ../lib/httpclient-4.5.13.jar:../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:../lib/httpcore-4.4.8.jar:../lib/json-20200518.jar`

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you in Windows or *nix?

Comment: I am working in Linux

Comment: Does the directory where your `.java` files are have the same parent as your `lib` directory?

Comment: Yes, they have the same parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved it by compiling the project to a JAR-File.